# Problems with installing oracle xe database on oracle linux (libnsl.so.1)

Tags: linux, oracle, installation

So I have set up an oracle linux 8 64-bit vm, since tries with other VMs always ended up missing libraries, I thought using the linux-os provided by Oracle themselves would have the needed libraries for a simple database installation.
I keep on running into issues with some 'libnsl.so.1' library, which cannot open a shared object file.

I have basically just set up this VM and manually downloaded two libraries for the preinstall, which worked fine after I installed the libraries.

Basically it looks like this:

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum localinstall /home/derfred3/Downloads/oracle-database-preinstall-18c-1.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm 
Last metadata expiration check: 1:12:24 ago on Sun 13 Dec 2020 12:13:16 PM CET.
Dependencies resolved.
================================================================================
 Package         Arch   Version                         Repository         Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 oracle-database-preinstall-18c
                 x86_64 1.0-1.el7                       @commandline       18 k
Installing dependencies:
 glibc-devel     x86_64 2.28-127.0.1.el8                ol8_baseos_latest 1.0 M
 ksh             x86_64 20120801-254.0.1.el8            ol8_appstream     927 k
 libaio-devel    x86_64 0.3.112-1.el8                   ol8_baseos_latest  19 k
 libstdc++-devel x86_64 8.3.1-5.1.0.1.el8               ol8_appstream     2.1 M
 libxcrypt-devel x86_64 4.1.1-4.el8                     ol8_baseos_latest  25 k
 lm_sensors-libs x86_64 3.4.0-21.20180522git70f7e08.el8 ol8_baseos_latest  59 k
 make            x86_64 1:4.2.1-10.el8                  ol8_baseos_latest 498 k
 sysstat         x86_64 11.7.3-5.el8                    ol8_appstream     425 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install  9 Packages

Total size: 5.0 M
Total download size: 5.0 M
Installed size: 19 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
(1/8): libaio-devel-0.3.112-1.el8.x86_64.rpm    139 kB/s |  19 kB     00:00    
(2/8): libxcrypt-devel-4.1.1-4.el8.x86_64.rpm   159 kB/s |  25 kB     00:00    
(3/8): lm_sensors-libs-3.4.0-21.20180522git70f7 362 kB/s |  59 kB     00:00    
(4/8): make-4.2.1-10.el8.x86_64.rpm             2.8 MB/s | 498 kB     00:00    
(5/8): ksh-20120801-254.0.1.el8.x86_64.rpm      2.9 MB/s | 927 kB     00:00    
(6/8): glibc-devel-2.28-127.0.1.el8.x86_64.rpm  3.0 MB/s | 1.0 MB     00:00    
(7/8): sysstat-11.7.3-5.el8.x86_64.rpm          2.8 MB/s | 425 kB     00:00    
(8/8): libstdc++-devel-8.3.1-5.1.0.1.el8.x86_64 3.0 MB/s | 2.1 MB     00:00    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                           5.0 MB/s | 5.0 MB     00:01     
warning: /var/cache/dnf/ol8_baseos_latest-e4c6155830ad002c/packages/libaio-devel-0.3.112-1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ad986da3: NOKEY
Oracle Linux 8 BaseOS Latest (x86_64)           3.0 MB/s | 3.1 kB     00:00    
Importing GPG key 0xAD986DA3:
 Userid     : "Oracle OSS group (Open Source Software group) <build@oss.oracle.com>"
 Fingerprint: 76FD 3DB1 3AB6 7410 B89D B10E 8256 2EA9 AD98 6DA3
 From       : /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Key imported successfully
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded.
Running transaction
  Preparing        :                                                        1/1 
  Installing       : glibc-devel-2.28-127.0.1.el8.x86_64                    1/9 
  Running scriptlet: glibc-devel-2.28-127.0.1.el8.x86_64                    1/9 
  Installing       : libxcrypt-devel-4.1.1-4.el8.x86_64                     2/9 
  Installing       : libstdc++-devel-8.3.1-5.1.0.1.el8.x86_64               3/9 
  Installing       : ksh-20120801-254.0.1.el8.x86_64                        4/9 
  Running scriptlet: ksh-20120801-254.0.1.el8.x86_64                        4/9 
  Installing       : make-1:4.2.1-10.el8.x86_64                             5/9 
  Running scriptlet: make-1:4.2.1-10.el8.x86_64                             5/9 
  Installing       : lm_sensors-libs-3.4.0-21.20180522git70f7e08.el8.x86_   6/9 
  Running scriptlet: lm_sensors-libs-3.4.0-21.20180522git70f7e08.el8.x86_   6/9 
  Installing       : sysstat-11.7.3-5.el8.x86_64                            7/9 
  Running scriptlet: sysstat-11.7.3-5.el8.x86_64                            7/9 
  Installing       : libaio-devel-0.3.112-1.el8.x86_64                      8/9 
  Running scriptlet: oracle-database-preinstall-18c-1.0-1.el7.x86_64        9/9 
  Installing       : oracle-database-preinstall-18c-1.0-1.el7.x86_64        9/9 
  Running scriptlet: oracle-database-preinstall-18c-1.0-1.el7.x86_64        9/9 
  Verifying        : libaio-devel-0.3.112-1.el8.x86_64                      1/9 
  Verifying        : libxcrypt-devel-4.1.1-4.el8.x86_64                     2/9 
  Verifying        : lm_sensors-libs-3.4.0-21.20180522git70f7e08.el8.x86_   3/9 
  Verifying        : make-1:4.2.1-10.el8.x86_64                             4/9 
  Verifying        : glibc-devel-2.28-127.0.1.el8.x86_64                    5/9 
  Verifying        : ksh-20120801-254.0.1.el8.x86_64                        6/9 
  Verifying        : libstdc++-devel-8.3.1-5.1.0.1.el8.x86_64               7/9 
  Verifying        : sysstat-11.7.3-5.el8.x86_64                            8/9 
  Verifying        : oracle-database-preinstall-18c-1.0-1.el7.x86_64        9/9 

Installed:
  glibc-devel-2.28-127.0.1.el8.x86_64                                           
  ksh-20120801-254.0.1.el8.x86_64                                               
  libaio-devel-0.3.112-1.el8.x86_64                                             
  libstdc++-devel-8.3.1-5.1.0.1.el8.x86_64                                      
  libxcrypt-devel-4.1.1-4.el8.x86_64                                            
  lm_sensors-libs-3.4.0-21.20180522git70f7e08.el8.x86_64                        
  make-1:4.2.1-10.el8.x86_64                                                    
  oracle-database-preinstall-18c-1.0-1.el7.x86_64                               
  sysstat-11.7.3-5.el8.x86_64                                                   

Complete!
[root@localhost ~]# yum localinstall /home/derfred3/Downloads/oracle-database-
oracle-database-preinstall-18c-1.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
[root@localhost ~]# yum localinstall /home/derfred3/Downloads/oracle-database-
oracle-database-preinstall-18c-1.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
[root@localhost ~]# yum localinstall /home/derfred3/Downloads/oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm 
Last metadata expiration check: 1:12:59 ago on Sun 13 Dec 2020 12:13:16 PM CET.
Dependencies resolved.
================================================================================
 Package                      Architecture Version     Repository          Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 oracle-database-xe-18c       x86_64       1.0-1       @commandline       2.3 G

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total size: 2.3 G
Installed size: 5.2 G
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded.
Running transaction
  Preparing        :                                                        1/1 
  Running scriptlet: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64                    1/1 
  Installing       : oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64                    1/1 
  Running scriptlet: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64                    1/1 
Exception java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/oui/lib/linux64/liboraInstaller.so: libnsl.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory occurred..
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/oui/lib/linux64/liboraInstaller.so: libnsl.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.osd.unix.OiipuUnixOps.loadNativeLib(OiipuUnixOps.java:388)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.osd.unix.OiipuUnixOps.<clinit>(OiipuUnixOps.java:130)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.oiipg.OiipgEnvironment.getEnv(OiipgEnvironment.java:201)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiix.OiixIniPair.instantiateEnvVars(OiixIniPair.java:299)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiix.OiixIniPair.updateValue(OiixIniPair.java:230)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiix.OiixIniPair.<init>(OiixIniPair.java:148)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiix.OiixIniFile.readFile(OiixIniFile.java:809)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiix.OiixIniFile.readIniFile(OiixIniFile.java:978)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiix.OiixIniFile.getProfileString(OiixIniFile.java:385)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiix.OiixOraparam.getOraparamProfileString(OiixOraparam.java:339)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiix.OiixOraparam.getOraparamProfileString(OiixOraparam.java:297)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiix.OiixOraparam.usePrereqChecker(OiixOraparam.java:417)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicSessionContext.setVariables(OiicSessionContext.java:1325)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicBaseInventoryApp.execute(OiicBaseInventoryApp.java:766)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicBaseInventoryApp.main_helper(OiicBaseInventoryApp.java:685)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicDetachHome.main(OiicDetachHome.java:420)
'DetachHome' failed.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicBaseInventoryApp.main_helper(OiicBaseInventoryApp.java:701)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicDetachHome.main(OiicDetachHome.java:420)
Exception java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/oui/lib/linux64/liboraInstaller.so: libnsl.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory occurred..
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/oui/lib/linux64/liboraInstaller.so: libnsl.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.osd.unix.OiipuUnixOps.loadNativeLib(OiipuUnixOps.java:388)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.osd.unix.OiipuUnixOps.<clinit>(OiipuUnixOps.java:130)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.oiipg.OiipgEnvironment.getEnv(OiipgEnvironment.java:201)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiix.OiixIniPair.instantiateEnvVars(OiixIniPair.java:299)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiix.OiixIniPair.updateValue(OiixIniPair.java:230)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiix.OiixIniPair.<init>(OiixIniPair.java:148)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiix.OiixIniFile.readFile(OiixIniFile.java:809)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiix.OiixIniFile.readIniFile(OiixIniFile.java:978)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiix.OiixIniFile.getProfileString(OiixIniFile.java:385)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiix.OiixOraparam.getOraparamProfileString(OiixOraparam.java:339)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiix.OiixOraparam.getOraparamProfileString(OiixOraparam.java:297)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiix.OiixOraparam.usePrereqChecker(OiixOraparam.java:417)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicSessionContext.setVariables(OiicSessionContext.java:1325)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicBaseInventoryApp.execute(OiicBaseInventoryApp.java:766)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicBaseInventoryApp.main_helper(OiicBaseInventoryApp.java:685)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicAttachHome.main(OiicAttachHome.java:696)
'AttachHome' failed.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicBaseInventoryApp.main_helper(OiicBaseInventoryApp.java:701)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicAttachHome.main(OiicAttachHome.java:696)
[SEVERE] An error occurred while registering the Oracle home. Verify logs in /var/log/oracle-database-xe-18c/results/oraInstall.log and /opt/oracle/oraInventory for more details and try again.
warning: %post(oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status 1

Error in POSTIN scriptlet in rpm package oracle-database-xe-18c
  Verifying        : oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64                    1/1 

Installed:
  oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64                                           

Complete!

[root@localhost ~]#
```

Can anyone help me with this?
It is quite frustrating to look at basically **any** online guide and never see them mention problems that can come up with this. Also searching the web for those problems seem to only direct me to those '*easy guide to install oracle 18c xe*' sites.

I might add that I am no linux specialist, but quite a newbie, so please consider this when answering. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest a different approach: why reinventing the wheel? Download one of **pre-built** virtual machines which are already configured and ready to use. Find them [here](https://www.oracle.com/downloads/developer-vm/community-downloads.html).

Comment: Well, I did not know that *pre-built* virtual machines are a thing. This basically fills the need of setting up an environment with a database, even though it avoids the described problem. Thank you, anyway as this is good enough for me.. for now :)